# Disable or use undo function in GAS for spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, undo

I am using onchange(). Makeing 2 change to the spreadsheet table. So when you make a change to the table there will another 2 change to the table after that. And when you try to use ctrl+z then the onchange() will be executed again :/ . So is there a way to disable the history function? Or can you call undo function from GAS? How could I know when the change is from a undo and do not make any change in the onchange function.

Comment: interesting. I wonder if the drive file's "last modified" shows the undo date or the reverted date, and if undo reverts changes on the revision history. both might help you detect the situation.